# Finding the two points of tangency on a circle when a point, from where the tangent is drawn, is given.

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

[image: See the image given]

Suppose I am given with point $P (x, y)$ and the equation of the circle, $C\equiv x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$. The centre of this circle is $C (-g, -f)$ and its radius, $r = \sqrt{g^2 + f^2 - c}$. Given these data can points $A$ and $B$ be determined?

Answer (score 1):

PAC is a right triangle,
so
$PA^2 + AC^2 = PC^2$.
Since you know AC and PC,
this determines PA.

A is at the intersection
of the circles
center C radius CA
and center P
radius PA.

You should be able to do the rest.